# Sum durations in bash

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I am getting execution time of various processes in a file from their respective log files. The file with execution time looks similar to following (it may have hundreds of entries)

```
1:00:01.11
2:2.20
1.02
```

The first line is `hours:minutes:seconds`, the second line is `minutes:seconds` and, the third is just `seconds`.

I want to sum all entries to come to a total execution time. How can I achieve this in bash? If not bash, then can you provide me some examples from other scripting language to sum timestamps?

Comment: Frankly, apart from getting the execution times from log files in a separate file, not tried anything on the sum of timestamps front. I searched stackexchange and related forums, found some examples but I could not figure out what logic I can use to differentiate 1st line vs 2nd line vs 3rd line (from example in my question) as not each line will have all 3...hours:minutes:seconds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To complement [Matt Jacob's elegant `perl` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42354652/45375) with a (POSIX-compliant) **`awk` solution**:

```
awk -F: '{ n=0; for(i=NF; i>=1; --i) secs += $i * 60 ^ n++ } END { print secs }' file
```

With the sample input, this outputs (the sum of all time spans in *seconds*):

```
3724.33
```

See the section below for how to format this value as a time span, similar to the input (`01:02:04.33`).

**Explanation:**

- `-F:` splits the input lines into fields by `:`, so that the resulting fields (`$1`, `$2`, ...) represent the hour, minute, and seconds components individually.
- `n=0; for(i=NF; i>=1; --i) secs += $i * 60 ^ n++` enumerates the fields in reverse order (first seconds, then minutes, then hours, if defined; `NF` is the number of fields) and multiplies each field with the appropriate multiple of 60 to yield an overall value in seconds, stored in variable `secs`, cumulatively across lines.
- `END { print secs }` is executed after all lines have been processed and simply prints the cumulative value in seconds.

---

#### Formatting the output as a time span:

*Custom output formatting* must be used:

```
awk -F: '
  { n=0; for(i=NF; i>=1; --i) secs += $i * 60 ^ n++ }
  END { 
    hours   = int(secs / 3600)
    minutes = int((secs - hours * 3600) / 60)
    secs    = secs % 60
    printf "%02d:%02d:%05.2f\n", hours, minutes, secs
  }
' file
```

The above yields (the equivalent of `3724.33` seconds):

```
01:02:04.33
```

The `END { ... }` block splits the total number of seconds accumulated in `secs` back into hours, minutes, and seconds, and outputs the result with appropriate formatting of the components using `printf`.

The reason that utilities such as `date` and *GNU* `awk`'s (nonstandard) date-formatting functions cannot be used to format the output is twofold:

- The standard time format specifier `%H` *wraps around* at 24 hours, so if the cumulative time span exceeds 24 hours, the output would be incorrect.
- Fractional seconds would be lost (the granularity of Unix time stamps is  *whole seconds*).

Answer (score 6):

The mostly-readable full `perl` script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $seconds = 0;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = reverse(split(/:/));

    for my $i (0 .. $#fields) {
        $seconds += $fields[$i] * 60 ** $i;
    }
}

print "$seconds\n";

__DATA__
1:00:01.11
2:2.20
1.02
```

Or, the barely-readable one-liner version:

```
$ perl -F: -wane '@F = reverse(@F); $seconds += $F[$_] * 60 ** $_ for 0 .. $#F; END { print "$seconds\n" }' times.log
```

Output:

```
3724.33
```

In both cases, we're splitting each line on the H:M:S separator `:` and then reversing the array so that we can process from right-to-left. To get the total time in seconds, we can rely on a neat trick where we multiply each field by powers of 60.

If you want the result in H:M:S format instead of raw seconds, [`strftime()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#strftime) from the POSIX core module makes it easy:

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);
print strftime('%H:%M:%S', gmtime($seconds)), "\n";
```

Output:

```
01:02:04
```

Comment: It would be even better if the final output could be parsed into h, m, s, although — nice answer regardless; Bear Down!

Comment: @l'L'l Ok, added. As a proud Wildcat alumnus, I felt compelled to give a 100% solution ;-)

Comment: Or even include the reverse in the loop.

Comment: An elegant solution overall, but there are two caveats regarding the use of `strftime` for formatting the output: if the total time span exceeds 24 hours, `%H` will wrap around, and the result will be incorrect - try adding `23:59:59` to the input. Also, fractional seconds are lost. The latter may not be an issue, but the former is a concern with a file containing hundreds of timestamps, as the OP states.

Comment: @mklement0 I agree. It's hard to know for sure without additional information, but I can always update the answer later on.